# How use argmax along axis to get maximum values in each column of numpy 2D array?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, max, argmax

For example I have the following 2D array:

```
array([[ 5.59635947,  1.42474555,  1.56519762],
       [ 6.16476541,  6.12324772,  5.32735447],
       [ 8.60258444,  7.16592582,  1.49555662],
       [ 0.63983973,  5.50249666,  3.52246942],
       [ 5.34002941,  4.87065573,  9.80725886]])
```

I use argmax along axis= 0 to get the position of maximum element in each column:

```
i = np.argmax(c,axis=0)
array([2, 2, 4])
```

Well, I **have already calculated the indices**. How can I get maximum element of each column?

When I write the following code:

```
dd_m= np.zeros(i.shape)
for k in np.arange(i.size):
    dd_m[k] = c[i[k],k]
```

I get right answer, which is:

```
 array([ 8.60258444,  7.16592582,  9.80725886])
```

Is there's more efficient or pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
c.max(axis=0)
```

Or:

```
np.max(c, axis=0)
```

Or if you have already calculated the indices:

```
c[i, np.arange(c.shape[1])]
```

Where `c` is your matrix, `i` is the found indices of max values.